# How can i increase the memory of Jupyter?

Tags: machine-learning, python, jupyter

### What I have:

I have a data set (35989 rows × 16109 columns) and is unfortunately confidential.

But i receive this error massage:

```
Unable to allocate 4.32 GiB for an array with shape (16109, 35994) and data type float64
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you cannot add more memory to your computer (or free up some of the memory), you could try 2 general approaches:

1. Read only some of the data into memory e.g. a subset of the rows or columns.
2. reduce the precision of the data from `float64` to `float32`.

From your error, it looks like you are loading data into a numpy array, so somewhere in your code, you would need to add this argument to the array creation step e.g.  `np.array(your_data, dtype=np.float32)`.

#### EDIT:

I don't think this is a rate limiting problem, or a `max_buffer_size` issue from Tornado (the library behind Jupyter).

You can try to see if your machine is actually running out of memory by using a tool called `htop` - just execute `htop` in a terminal (or first `sudo apt install htop` if it isn't already installed).  That shows the total amount of memory (RAM) available on your machine, it looks something like this:

[image: htop example]
This example shows the machine has 16 cores and 62.5 Gb memory - 6.14Gb of that is occupied.

Watch that view while you run your code. If the memory bar becomes full before the crash, you know you ran out of RAM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm using Jupyter Notebook.  I founded this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948003/how-to-increase-jupyter-notebook-memory-limit) about this problem. It doesn't  work unfortunately.

Comment: That setting seems to be rather about how much memory is used in a buffer while reading data. That is different to the amount of memory that is available to actually save a full array. As far as I know, there are no limits on that - just your machine. I'll update my answer with another idea.